# How to optimize jQuery and CSS - jittery scroll transitions

Tags: jquery, performance

I haven't found an answer here that remedies my solution -

I recently implemented a bunch of addClass & removeClass jQuery behavior on my personal site that is triggered when the element comes into view.  I have the CSS set to a pixel size that places it off screen, and when the element is scrolled to, a class is added to the element that brings it back on screen.

I'm not receiving any JS errors in the console, and all of my images are compressed.  Not sure what could be causing this, but it's pretty gross looking.  Any tips would be amazing.

Here is the site - [Inline Link](http://www.justincefai.co)

jQuery function example

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var sT = $(this).scrollTop();
    var sB = sT + $(window).height();
    var tag = $(".outer-box-l-1");

    if ($(tag).position().top < sB) {
      $(tag).addClass("visible");
    } else {
      $(tag).removeClass("visible");
    }
  });
```

CSS

```
.outer-box-l-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 8px 40px 8px;
  width: 35%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: unset;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-850px, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.outer-box-l-1.visible {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Not at all jittery on iPad. What browser are you using?

Comment: I checked it in Chrome.  It actually looks decent in Safari for some reason, but some of the animations and styling are lost haha.  Headache central.

Comment: hmm not sure. Great looking site btw.

Comment: @Cybernetic Thanks!  Working on it!